# Правильный способ выровнять иконки по центру

Tags: html, css

Нужно выровнять иконки по центру-вертикально и горизонтально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Svg иконки разных размеров, а их контейнер, белый круг всегда одного размера: 100х100. Выравниваю через flexbox, но мне кажется это кривой и громоздкий способ

```
.icon-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: В вырванном из контекста коде флекс вполне подойдет. Вообще не понятно, что именно вам не нравится в этом варианте и чем он громоздкий? Есть множество вариантов решить эту проблему, и в зависимости от общей задачи один вариант может подойти больше, а другой меньше.

Comment: text-align:center; line-height:100px;

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox конечно короче но и старые варианты которые везде работают забывать не надо

**смотрите**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-cell span {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell"><span>ico1</span></div>
    <div class="table-cell"><span>ico2</span></div>
    <div class="table-cell"><span>ico3</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox это самый удобный и красивый способ на данный момент.

Скажем так, все остальные способы выглядят более громоздкими.

Comment: Мне тоже так кажется. Но с другой стороны, не громоздко ли будет столько стилей прописывать. Может быть есть более верное решение?

Comment: @StepanIvanov как мне кажется flex решение будет самым лаконичным

Comment: @StepanIvanov, на сегодняшний день флексы это самый короткий способ выровнять элементы по центру.